# Access to other window of application - WhiteStack

Tags: c#, automated-tests, white-framework

I would like to test to Outlook application and send an email to me by using White Stack framework. I implemented code who click on 'New Item' and after that the new window appears. I want to type a my mail to TextBox 'To' but I don't know how get to access to second window 'Untitled - Message (HTML)'. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8opeJ.png)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void mail()
    {
        var application = Application.Launch(appPatch);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var window = application.GetWindow(appTitle, InitializeOption.NoCache);
       
        SearchCriteria searchCriteriaNewEmail = SearchCriteria.ByText("New Email");
        Button buttonNewEmail = window.Get<Button>(searchCriteriaNewEmail);
        buttonNewEmail.Click();


        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        string windowTitle = "Untitled‬ - Message(HTML)";
        var window2 = application.GetWindow(windowTitle, InitializeOption.NoCache);
        SearchCriteria searchCriteriaTo = SearchCriteria.ByText("To");
        TextBox tbxTo = window2.Get<TextBox>(searchCriteriaTo);
        tbxTo.BulkText = "mymail@gmail.com";

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        window.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for spam. I made a mistake and put the wrong name of the application. There should be space-bar at the end of the name  - "Untitled‬ - Message(HTML) "

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "second window" is in the same process id, so with that you can't simply use the `.GetWindow()` method.

For MDI applications you should use `MdiChild()`, or if it is a modal window, use `.ModalWindow()` on the parent window, or go back to the application then use `Window()` to get the window.

I would add that getting the window by it's title is not recommended, since that will change as you type the new title of the e-mail.